# windows server backup to any subfolder

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, backup

I´d like to know when i make full system backup in windows server 2008, how to chose destination folder. By default in local drives backup, it only allows to chose the destination Volume.
Thanks

Comment: Share a folder, and put it into network backup mode.

Comment: I thought about this method. Is this the better one? It has no performance impact? Thanks.